# how can I get response value (json) to String via Java

Tags: java, json, rest

I have the json format like following

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "name1"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "name2"
    }
    ]
}
```

---

I want to filter name from it , Array name = [name1, name2]

---

```
    @GET (Web service)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
    public Response getItem() {
        ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
        HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic(getUserName(),getUserPassword());
        config.register(feature);
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
        WebTarget service = client.target(getURI() + "/Item");
        Response response = service.request().header("Content-Type", "application/json").get();
        return response;
    }
```

---

I have already tried here
 http://gotoanswer.com/?q=How+to+Parse+the+this+JSON+Response+in+JAVA

then success.

But how can I do to dynamicaly get json format from Response to string
so that I can input to String jsonString.

---

Comment: this https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath may be helpful, a light and simple library to parse json

Comment: @user5121761 does [this](http://ankursinghal86.blogspot.in/2014/11/json-to-hashmap-parsing-json-string.html) help you

Answer (score 0):

When you are parsing your json, the 'items' is an array in your json. So if you try to get the 'items' you will need to type cast it to JSONArray. And iterating on this JSONArray you can get the values of the array using the attributes defined like 'name' and 'id'.

Can you try like this?

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray items = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("items");

for (int 1 = 0; i < items.length(); i++)
{
    System.out.println( items.get(i).get("name");
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: if you add more info, I bet you will have better chance to be recognized ;)

Comment: :) @KickButtowski ..appreciate your feedback and added some information around it.

Comment: you are welcome, but your wording is little off. for example, please reread your first sentence

Comment: @KickButtowski thank you :), tried to make it sensible. If you feel anything else, please feel free to change it or add to it. Your addition will help me.